# Converting my C++ code to Java: Translating multiple inheritance

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance

First day using Java. Very basic question: I have three base classes, multiply-inherited by many classes. Each of these base classes has lots of implementation with few abstract methods:

```
class Consumer { /* lots of stuff */ };
class Producer { /* lots of stuff */ };
class Logger { /* lots of stuff */ };

class A : public Consumer, Producer, Logger {}
...
class Z : public Consumer, Producer, Logger {}
```

Now I know I can turn two of three base classes into interfaces and multiple-inherit the 2 interfaces and extend one class. Inadequate because of all the implementation in these base classes that doesn't make sense to duplicate into many subclasses.

I'm reading some stuff on delegation or composition, and I don't know how to apply this here. Basically my thought processes have been patterned by my C++ experience. **What is the path of least resistance to convert my C++ class structure to Java?**

I can fill out the base classes more if needed, but hopefully not necessary.

Comment: Are Consumer, Producer and Logger actual classes, or are they renamed for this question?

Comment: my guess is that it's renamed for this question… ;-)

Comment: @zmo I don't need to know their names, I need to know at what level they operate. I mean, Consumer of *what*?

Comment: anyway, I'm voting for this question to be closed because too broad, as it does not have an obvious simple solution to the problem.

Comment: @zmo well, that's not a requirement, but I'm a bit afraid that this design cannot be salvaged myself. Consumer and Producer are too generic, Logger should be created using composition.

Comment: @owlstead Sorry I didn't watch my own question. Yes, Consumer, Producer and Logger are all actual classes in my design. Consumer consumes message that an upstream Producer-derived class gives it. The Consumer is optionally a thread with a queue. Logger is just a logging facility where any class can write to one file.

Comment: @zmo I think zicow56 has provided enough guidance that I can go from there. I accept that I didn't give enough info and the questions seems broad as a result. Still wrapping my mind around translating design concepts as opposed to just code. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options:

Create 3 interfaces for Consumer, Producer and Logger and make the classes A and Z implementing them. Of course for each class you have to provide an implementation. If the implementation is the same make a more generic class (it could be abstract, you probably won't need to instantiate it) implementing the 3 interfaces and then make the classes A and Z extending the abstract class.

As you said in your post it seems this solutions don't fit your needs , so use delegation instead, in the classes A and Z put 3 new fields (as instance variable) of Consumer, Producer and Logger type (you can instantiate them in the constructor)  and then put methods which are wrappers for the Consumer, producer and Logger methods.

Comment: This is actually pretty practicle advice. Both of your suggestions are workable I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> *What is the path of least resistance to convert my C++ class structure to Java?*

take a pen and paper, *rethink your problem* and make a design that's closer to how Java works.

There's no magical rule that will transform any given problem with multiple inheritance into another without it. Given the situation, you may want to separate concerns by creating multiple classes with a reference to each other, whereas you had only one in C++… But then it's up to the specific problem you're dealing with, how you'd build your hierarchy of classes and interfaces and how the resulting different class instances will relate to each other.